# System.Windows.PropertyPath - can this class help me with reflection on deep-nested properties (types)?

Tags: data-binding, reflection, c#-4.0, system.reflection, propertyinfo

I've been sitting lately on the topic of Reflection, mainly with the purpose of instantiating a New class and setting properties on fields.. By path... 
Where, for example I might have a class called Games, with public property -

```
Game myGame = new Game()

myGame.GamingProperties.HowToPlay = "bla bla bla";
myGame.StateProperties.CreationTime = DateTime.Today;
```

So for example I have to set value (with reflection magic) on property with a path of: "GamingProperties.HowToPlay"

Until now I've been using the "[PropertyReflector](http://blog.guymahieu.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/02/propertyreflector.cs)" class by Guy Mahieu - which does exactly what I need, but slowly when it comes to reflecting/de-serializing 100,000-s of objects.

Bit later I found out that it is possible to set property values much much faster by using "Expression Trees" (and a project like "[FastReflection](http://fastreflection.codeplex.com/)") was a good example.. But I got stuck now with the FastReflection because I can't set values properly on nested types...

Anyhow – the question is – whether `System.Windows.PropertyPath` could help me somehow with all this? Is it even related? Maybe I could use it for my needs, or use the `.Binding` methods (that are closely related with `System.Windows.PropertyPath`)?

I hope that I was clear and not too messy with my question and I will be grateful for any hints, suggestions...

Comment: Why can't you set values on nested types with FastReflection? It should be possible if you were using `Expression`s directly.

Comment: Yes. I guess I can - just have to figure out how to do it right... :)

Comment: then why don't you ask a question about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. The PropertyPath is used by the WPF binding system to tie DependencyProperties to other properties (either dependency or regular). When binding to a dependency property, the binding system can use the property path to resolve the bound property using WPF metadata. When binding to a CLR property, it has to use .NET reflection to resolve the property.

In either case, it's not generally used to set CLR properties, but it can with two-way bindings.

It won't provide a speed boost for that many objects and I doubt it is a solution to your problem.